# error during addslashes() function in php

Tags: php, trim, addslashes

html form code-

```
<td width="75">
<input name="txtQty[]" type="text" id="txtQty[]" size="5" 
 value="<?php echo $ct_qty; ?>" class="box" onKeyUp="checkNumber(this);">
```

when I submit form I calls following script-

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
if (isset($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_POST[$key] =  trim(addslashes($value));
    }
}

if (isset($_GET)) {
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $_GET[$key] = trim(addslashes($value));
    }
}   
}
```

**error-**

> Warning: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\products\library\config.php on line 53

I think this script is being used just to trim input but I  dont know what this addslash function does and why this error coming.

Comment: addslashes() just returns a string with backslashes in front of predefined characters.

Comment: about the error you received.. make sure that $value is a string...

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious? `$value` is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply this code on an `int` value then you remove these function like this

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
if (isset($_POST)) { 
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        $_POST[$key] =  $value; 
    } 
} 

if (isset($_GET)) { 
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
        $_GET[$key] = $value; 
    } 
}    
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chandraveer singh, That one worked. btw, the code snippet is from plaincart ecommerce shopping cart tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

1. The whole approach is wrong.
   Upon receiving user supplied data you have to **strip** slashes, added by magic quotes, not add.
2. About array approach it says 2 answers already posted, I hope it is well explained here.
   Not so well, but anyway.

So, you will need 2 code snippets.
A first one is stripslashes_deep() from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

A second one you will get after you tell us, why did you think you need the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

the error said , the `addslashes` function try to Quote string with slashes , 
but the $value the parameter is not a string is an **array**,
 what CONTAIN the `$_GET` ?

its because that the page that call to this script pass a array . `txtQty[]`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Just echo $value before passing it to addslashes(), then you should see the problem immediately.