# PHP Argument Order Issue: Bug or Errata?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and encountered some odd behavior that may or may not be a bug in my version of PHP (5.4.13).  I found a case where the sequence of function arguments matters in the function declaration. The in the following example:

```
class Book {
  function __construct() { }

  public static function withDescriptors($isNotOrmObject, $isArray, $isScalar) {
    $instance = new self();
    // initialization here
    return $instance;
  }
}
```

Invoking withDescriptors causes an **'array to string conversion'** exception.  The error is thrown when withDescriptors is invoked, ie. withDescriptors is never actually executed.  However, switching the object parameter with the array parameter solves the problem. I.e.

```
public static function withDescriptors($isArray, $isNotOrmObject, $isScalar){ ....
```

Is this a known characteristic of PHP or is this a bug?

**More explicitly:**

```
class Book {
  function __construct() { }

  public static function withDescriptors($isNotOrmObject, $isArray, $isScalar) {
    $instance = new self();
    // initialization here
    return $instance;
  }
}

$book = Book::withDescriptors($isNotORMobject, $isArray, $isScalar);
```

**FAILS** and

```
class Book {
  function __construct() { }

  public static function withDescriptors($isArray, $isNotORMobject, $isScalar) {
    $instance = new self();
    // initialization here 
    return $instance;
  }
}

$book = Book::withDescriptors($isArray, $isNotORMobject, $isScalar);
```

**WORKS** great.  The **ONLY** difference is the **parameter sequence**, the "initialization here" code is identical.

Comment: Of course it does matter. In any language it does matter, even strictly typed ones. How do you expect it to behave with 3 scalar arguments? It must know which argument is what later on.

Comment: You don't seem really 'New' to PHP to me

Comment: Looks like 'somewhere' in your code, PHP expects/treats an array argument as a string. Possibly, the object you're using is able to be converted to a string via a 'magic' [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method. Because of this, the error does not show up. However, not sure what is causing the problem without the *actual* source code

Comment: @thaJeztah - NotORM probably does have a __toString() method, but I am still not sure why would it's location in the parameter list matter.

Comment: If you dont want to remember the order of parameter from your next project than you should use this approch:

    function myfunction( $holder = array()){
    // do something with your parameters
    }

and call it:

    myfunction(array('r' => 52, 'g' => 53, 'b' => 80));

off course at least you get the idea. Thanks

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Not sure you understood the question.  The strongly typed languages I know (C++, Java) do not care what order the argument are listed in the function definition.

Comment: Well, apparently, the *second* argument is somewhere used as a string. If you pass it an array, then PHP converts that to a String somewhere, causing the *warning*. However, if you pass an *Object* that is capable of being converted to a string, then the second argument is 'OK(isn)' as it will automatically convert to a String and the warning is not output. It's not the *order* that's the point here, it's the *type of* argument passed as the second argument.

Comment: *"The strongly typed languages I know (C++, Java) do not care what order the argument are listed in the function definition."* - There must be a big misunderstanding here. Both of those languages accept  arguments in the same order when you call a function as in the declaration.

Comment: @thaJeztah I am trying to digest your answer. When the parameters are listed in the exception-creating order the body of withDescriptors is not executed, or at east xdebug fails before reaching the breakpoint on the first line.  Are you implying that when withDescriptors is called, PHP does additional processing on the arguments (aside from just copying them) before executing the function body?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some good answers here but this particular situation arose from a bug in the PHP interpreter.

Comment: I'm often one of the first to mention how crappy PHP's parser is.  But the question's code does not demonstrate any interpreter bugs; it will work in every modern (5.0+) version of PHP.  Absent further information, this answer is a guess at best, and misleading at worst.

Comment: @cHao Well the code is there and it sure didn't work on the 5.x version I was using, parameter declaration sequence should not matter so long as arguments are passed in the declared order.  That is the correct answer so your down vote is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: Really?  Did you try running your example code?  Cause [i did](http://ideone.com/Sm2W6L), and it works just fine.

Comment: @CHao Your code is also wrong as I specified a NotORM object not ANY old class, i,e. you have $isNotORMobject = new stdclass;  Whether a specific NotORM object is needed is also irrelevant, the problem should not arise.

Comment: The problem *doesn't* arise. It is simply impossible for PHP itself to get confused like that. (Much like in most other dynamically typed languages, type is a property of values, not variables.)  Now, your initialization code very well might get confused, if you're playing with `func_get_args()`, `call_user_func_array(...)` etc and are using the wrong indexes.  But i guarantee that if i had access to an example that actually failed the way you say it does, i could trace this particular bug to either that code or some other PHP code it uses.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't get the *warning* in your second example, is that the `Object` you're passing as the second parameter is implementing a magic `__toString()` method. PHP is not a *strong typed* language, but more recent versions have *limited* capabilities of *type hinting*.

To illustrate the warning;

```
function saySomething($shouldBeAString)
{
    echo $shouldBeAString
}

saySomething(array('hello'));
```

Outputs
    'Array'

and a warning `array to string conversion`

```
class Foo {
   public function __toString() {
       return 'Hi I am Foo';
   }
}

$bar = new Foo();

 saySomething($bar);
```

Will output

```
'Hi I am Foo'
```

*Without warning*

As mentioned, PHP offers *limited* type hinting. You can specify a required 'class/object type' and 'array' as accepted arguments, but *not* scalar types, like 'string', 'int', 'bool' etc.

```
function (array $myarray) {
    // will only accept arrays
    // or something that implements array-access
}

function (Foo $var) {
    // Will only accept 'Foo' objects
}
```

#### Polymorphism / Function overloading

Some other languages allow defining the same method/function multiple times, but with a different signature (other argument types). PHP does not explicitly support this.

For example, in other languages, this is allowed:

```
function doSomething(string $arg1) { ......}

function doSomething(array $arg1) { .... }

function doSomething(string $arg1, string $arg2) { ... }
```

In those languages, depending on the type and number of arguments, variant 1, 2 or 3 will be executed. PHP does not support this as it requires functions/methods to have a *unique* name. PHP will therefore complain that function `doSomething()` is already defined.

However, you can create something similar in PHP in several ways;

```
 // rename the functions/methods so that they have a unique name

function _doSomething1(string $arg1) { ......}

function _doSomething2(array $arg1) { .... }

function _doSomething3(string $arg1, string $arg2) { ... }


// create the 'wrapper' function *without arguments specified*
function doSomething() {

    // determin which variant should be executed
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $args = func_get_args();

    if ($numargs == 2) {
        // 2 arguments -> variant 3
        return call_user_func_array('_doSomething3', $args);
    } else if {$numargs == 1) {
        if (is_array($args[0]) {
            // first argument is an array
            return call_user_func_array('_doSomething2', $args);
        } else {
            return call_user_func_array('_doSomething1', $args);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** code above is ***'fake' code***, just to illustrate the idea!

Comment: Nice explanation. In my case if we add two parameters to saySomething and make two different choices for parameter sequence -> saySomething($isArray, $isObject, $isScalar) and saySomething($isObject,$isArray, $isScalar); though the function bodies are otherwise identical saySomething($isObject,$isArray, $isScalar) FAILS and saySomething($isArray, $isObject, $isScalar) runs OK.

Comment: Yes. It's called polymorphism and PHP does *not* (explicitly) support this, although you can mimic something similar, I'll try to add that to my answer

Comment: Once again, nice examples.  However, this doesn't explain why the non-polymorphic case is failing... check out the two examples at the end of my question.

Comment: Those examples still are 'fake' code, not PHP? The problem/special case will be somewhere in the *initialization here* part. As I tried to explain, apparently, somewhere in your code, the *second* argument is treated as a *string*. If an *array* is converted to a string by PHP, a warning is shown. If a *Object* that *supports* conversion to a string (via `__toString()`), the conversion to string is performed without warning. In other words, **the constructor expects the _second_ parameter to be a String, or an _Object_ that supports `__toString()` An Array does _not_ fall in those categories**

Comment: The initialization here code and variable names are the same in both examples so the location of each parameter should not matter then... seem like it is a bug in the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Without the actual code it's hard to tell that? Normally a `Notice: Array to string conversion` should also tell you which *line* raises the notice? Like in this question: [PHP Notice: Array to string conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983329/php-notice-array-to-string-conversion). If (for example) somewhere inside your code `call_user_func_array()` is used, then the arguments may be used in the *wrong* order?

Answer (score 1):

In general, order matters in function arguments. 
The only time it doesn't is when arguments are the same type or your function implements something like get opt long.

Comment: Please expound.  In other languages (eg. Java) the language does not care in which order you list the arguments when defining a function - this would be a style choice.

Comment: Not in most C based syntax langs. always better to follow the function signature. Makes things self documenting as well.

Comment: In most languages I've encountered, it would simply fail. Since most languages are implemented in C it's a safe bet to just follow the order in the API doc.

Comment: I think you are missing the question, check out the examples at the end of the description.